# \xleftrightarrows command in TikZ with arrows matching the LaTeX font

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows

There is the command `\xrightarrow` that inserts an arrow that extends with the text you put above and/or under it.
There is also the command `\rightleftarrows` (notice the "s" at the end) that display two arrows, one under the other, although they are *not* extensible and (if I'm not mistaken) require additionally the `mathtools` package.
(The above is of course also valid for the "dual" leftarrows)

As far as I know, there isn't a command `\xrightarrows` that extends with the text above/under it and creates and arrow like `\rightleftarrows` (I googled it and couldn't find any straightforward solution). Maybe it is contained in some obscure package - but if the package isn't already in my distribution I would prefer not haveing to install it (because if I want to compile my document somewhere else, problems might crop up!).

Therefore: How can one program this  `\xrightarrows` command in TikZ such that

- the arrow tips look exactly like the LaTeX arrow tips (and if I change the LaTeX font the arrow tips from the TikZ drawing also change accordingly)
- the arrows themselves look exactly like the ones `\xrightarrows` produces, when the parameters for the text under or above  are empty (i.e. not text is present) or there is so little text that the arrows don't have to extend.

Comment: `\rightleftarrows` needs `amssymb`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here it is. This should start as the starting point.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}     %% this is not needed. just for demo
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand{\xrightarrows}{ O{}O{} }{%
\mathrel{%
\vcenter{\hbox{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[minimum width=1cm,minimum height=1ex,anchor=south,align=center] (a){\text{\vphantom{hg}#1}\\[0.5ex] \vphantom{hg}#2};
  \draw[<-] ([yshift=0.35ex]a.west) -- ([yshift=0.35ex]a.east);
  \draw[->] ([yshift=-0.35ex]a.west) -- ([yshift=-0.35ex]a.east);
\end{tikzpicture}
}}%
}%
}
\begin{document}
  $\xleftarrow[under]{over}$

  $\xrightarrow[under]{over} \rightleftarrows$

  Now the new arrows

  $A \xrightarrows B$  \quad $A \xrightarrows[some ght][some text again] B$ 

  $A \xrightarrows[some text here] B$  \quad $A \xrightarrows[][some text again] B$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This was really useful to me too !